# How to obtain top 5 players for each game from a MySQL high score board?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to setup a high score board to be displayed in my arcade game room. My target is to display the top 5 players for each game from the table `GAME`.

I've created three tables:

Table GAME :

```
+----------+--------------+
| id_game | name_game |
+----------+--------------+
| 1 | PAC MAN | 
| 2 | GALAXIAN |
| 3 | XEVIOUS |
```

table PLAYER :

```
+----------+---------------+
| id_player | name_player |
+----------+---------------+
| 1 | BRUNO | 
| 2 | STEVE |
```

table SCORE :

```
+----------+----------+-----------+------+------+
| id_score | id_game | id_player | date | score | 
+----------+----------+-----------+------+------+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 01/10/15 | 230234 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 04/10/15 | 120234 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 03/10/15 | 440224 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 06/10/15 | 200000 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 09/10/15 | 330233 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 01/10/15 | 510000 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | 01/10/15 | 730874 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 01/10/15 | 990900 |
| 9 | 3 | 1 | 01/10/15 | 444000 |
```

I would like some help to build the sql code to produce something like this :

PAC MAN

```
1. BRUNO 510000 PTS 01/10/15
2. STEVE 330233 PTS 09/10/15
3. XXXXX 230233 PTS 02/10/14
4. YYYYY 130233 PTS 06/10/15
5. ZZZZZ 030233 PTS 10/10/13
```

GALAXIAN

```
1. STEVE 990900 PTS 01/10/15
2. BRUNO 730874 PTS 01/10/15
3. XXXXX 230233 PTS 02/10/14
4. YYYYY 130233 PTS 06/10/15
5. ZZZZZ 030233 PTS 10/10/13
```

If the same player did more than one score on the same game, only his/her best score should be displayed. Can you help me to set up the code for doing this?

Comment: Rather than all the `<br>` tags necessary to get your tables to show, you can highlight a block of text and use the `{}` or `ctl-k` to format it as a "code block" which will preserve whitespace and give it a fixed width font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d79/13)

```
SELECT MAX(s.score) AS score, p.name_player, g.name_game
FROM GAME g
JOIN SCORE s ON s.id_game = g.id_game
JOIN PLAYER p ON p.id_player = s.id_player
GROUP BY p.id_player, g.id_game
ORDER BY g.id_game, score
```

Well, I still have an issue with your query above :-(
The query displays well the best score of per unique player, but the date associated is not correct. The 'date' field still gives the first date from the first score done per player. 
Let me illustrate this.
 I just add the DATE value to the first line of your query, which gives :

```
 SELECT MAX(s.score) AS score, p.name_player, g.name_game, date
FROM GAME g
JOIN SCORE s ON s.id_game = g.id_game
JOIN PLAYER p ON p.id_player = s.id_player
GROUP BY p.id_player, g.id_game
ORDER BY g.id_game, score


+----------+----------+-----------+------+------+
| id_score | id_game | id_player | date | score | 
+----------+----------+-----------+------+------+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 01/10/12 | 230234 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 04/10/13 | 120234 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 03/10/14 | 440224 |
```

Your query will return this :
440224 1 1  **01/10/12** 
But I'm expecting this : 440224 1 1 **03/10/14**
I tried to add max(date) here in there but I guess there is obviously something more complex to do?

Comment: Well, this query is almost the one I need. Just had to add a 'DESC' command on the last line in order to have the highest score first. 
Now just need to limit the result with maximum 5 players per game. Is it possible starting your query?

Comment: Sure! Hold on, I'll fix the query.

Answer (score 1):

You would want something like this. The first query is probably the one you would actually use to run it against your own tables. The second example you can run directly in mysql and fudge the data as required.

```
select
  g.name_game,
  p.name_player,
  max(s.score),
  s.date
from
  game g

  inner join score s on
    s.id_game = g.id_game

  inner join player p on
    p.id_player = s.id_player
where
  g.name_game = 'PAC MAN'
group by
  g.name_game,
    p.name_player
ORDER BY
  s.score asc
LIMIT
  5;

select
  g.name_game,
  p.name_player,
  max(s.score),
  s.date
from
  (
    select  1 id_game, 'PAC MAN' name_game union all
    select  2 id_game, 'GALAXIAN' name_game union all
    select  3 id_game, 'XEVIOUS' name_game
  ) g

  inner join (
    select 1 id_score, 1 id_game, 1 id_player, '01/10/15' date, 230234 score union all
    select 2 id_score, 1 id_game, 2 id_player, '04/10/15' date, 120234 score union all
    select 3 id_score, 1 id_game, 1 id_player, '03/10/15' date, 440224 score union all
    select 4 id_score, 1 id_game, 1 id_player, '06/10/15' date, 200000 score union all
    select 5 id_score, 1 id_game, 2 id_player, '09/10/15' date, 330233 score union all
    select 6 id_score, 1 id_game, 1 id_player, '01/10/16' date, 410000 score union all
    select 6 id_score, 1 id_game, 1 id_player, '01/10/15' date, 510000 score union all
    select 7 id_score, 2 id_game, 1 id_player, '01/10/15' date, 730874 score union all
    select 8 id_score, 2 id_game, 2 id_player, '01/10/15' date, 990900 score union all
    select 9 id_score, 3 id_game, 1 id_player, '01/10/15' date, 444000 score
  ) s on
    s.id_game = g.id_game

  inner join (
    select '1' id_player, 'BRUNO' name_player union all
    select '2' id_player, 'STEVE' name_player 
  ) p on
    p.id_player = s.id_player
where
  g.name_game = 'PAC MAN'
group by
  g.name_game,
    p.name_player
ORDER BY
  s.score asc
LIMIT
  5;
```

Maybe next time post what you have tried?

You could also use a group by if you wanted them all in the same query. Just replace [game_name] with the name of the game you want.

Comment: @Bruno please can you mark as answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: There is something wrong when I run it on my DB, see :
pacman Tyrem 540300,
pacman Bill 435430 ,
pacman Marco 420990,
pacman Fred 256730,
pacman Darth Nuno 345000
Regarding the score, Darth Nuno should be a the 4rd position, and Fred the 5th.
I've defined 'score' field from the SCORE table as in Integer. Could it be the problem somehow?